# Updating converted Lead field

Tags: lead-conversion, update

How can i update the statecode of a lead which is converted.

I am trying to update statecode and countrycode of leads through dataloader. But i get records with errors "Cannot reference converted lead". I am curious to know that if there is any way to update those fields.

Answer (score 0):

SFDC  will not allow you to use Converted Lead as a reference for any Custom object record
When Lead is convereted (It creates Contact, account , Opportunity)
Even you will not able to View the Lead Record.

it will not show Lead record, shows new created object.

change the query,retrive only unconverted Leads.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring 16 release there is new feature introduced "Update Fields on Converted Leads".

We all know that once a Lead is converted, the data is only accessible in a read-only fashion via the Converted Leads report. But now, users with specified permissions can update fields and  picklist values or Leads already converted."

[Update Details for Converted Leads in Salesforce Classic](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_sales_leads_edit_converted_leads.htm)

Comment: I tried this document but i am stuck now since Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation is not editable.

Comment: You cannot modify default adminstrator profile clone the default profile and make the changes @p.samruddhi

Comment: By doing this too i am getting error while updating the records.